# React-native-maps module, missing gradle files?

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, expo, react-native-maps

I'm trying to set up react-native-maps module at my react-native app, however the component I've put in the code is blank.

To configure it properly I'm following the instructions (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md), however at the very first step I've encountered a problem.

The android/settings.gradle file is missing, even the android directory. Should I launch some command to generate these? The remaining screens seem to work.

There are plenty of gradle files in node_modules folder, the one from expo module could be the match, but changing it doesn't seem right.

Where is the settings.gradle file located by default?

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Than please check my answer. You don't need to follow any integration steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged expo in your question:

**If you are using Expo** you don't have to got through the integration steps, as react-native-maps is already included in Expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/

Just import the `MapView` from Expo:

```
...
import { MapView } from 'expo';
...
```

**If you are not using Expo** the settings.gradle file should look like this:

```
rootProject.name = '<your appname>'
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')

include ':app'
```

Comment: So Expo doesn't expose gradle files to the developers?

Comment: Yes they don't do that. If they would they could not offer the feature set they are currently offering.

Answer (score 0):

for ''Where is the settings.gradle file located by default?'' android->app and (usually last file is)settings.gradle